# QTreeWidget: How to change sizeHint dynamically?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

I have a **QTreeWidget** where the **TopLevelIteps** are replaced by a custom widget. Said widget have its maximum and minimum Heights animated with a **QStateMachine**.

QTreeWidget (GIF):
[image: QTreeWidget(gif)]

Custom Widget Animation (GIF):
[image: Custom Widget Animation(gif)]

The problem is that the rows will not adjust its height to fit the custom widget when it expands:

Row height fixed size (GIF):
[image: Row height fixed size(gif)]

Causing overlap between the widget items instead of pushing each other away like this:

The results that I'm after (GIF):
[image: The results that I'm after(gif)]

I tried using **setSizeHint()** on the top level item to but it creates a big empty space between items/widgets:

Using setSizeHint()(GIF):
[image: Using setSizeHint()(gif)]

I'm thinking that maybe I have to implement sizeHint() but I'm not really sure what to put there. Or is there a better approach to this problem?

I would really appreciate some hints.

Example code:

```
# Custom Widget
class ExpandableFrame(QFrame):

    def __init__(self):
        QFrame.__init__(self)

        # Default Properties
        self.setFixedSize(200,50)
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: #2e4076; border: 2px solid black; border-radius: 10px;')
     
        # Setup expand button
        self.expandToggle = QToolButton()
        self.expandToggle.setText('[]')
        self.expandToggle.setMaximumSize(10,20)
        self.expandToggle.setCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)

        # Setup layout
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
        layout.addWidget(self.expandToggle)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.expandArea()

    # Animates minimumHeight and maximumHeight
    def expandArea(self):

        heigth = self.height()
        newHeigth = 100

        machine = QStateMachine(self)

        state1 = QState()
        state1.assignProperty(self, b'minimumHeight', heigth)
        state1.assignProperty(self, b'maximumHeight', heigth)

        state2 = QState()
        state2.assignProperty(self, b'minimumHeight', newHeigth)
        state2.assignProperty(self, b'maximumHeight', newHeigth)

        # Create animations
        expandAnim = QPropertyAnimation(self, 'minimumHeight')
        closeAnim = QPropertyAnimation(self, 'maximumHeight')
        expandAnim.setDuration(125)
        closeAnim.setDuration(125)
        expandAnim.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve.Linear)  

        # Create event transitions
        eventTransition1 = QEventTransition(self.expandToggle, QEvent.MouseButtonPress)
        eventTransition1.setTargetState(state2)
        eventTransition1.addAnimation(expandAnim)
        state1.addTransition(eventTransition1)

        eventTransition2 = QEventTransition(self.expandToggle, QEvent.MouseButtonPress)
        eventTransition2.setTargetState(state1)
        eventTransition2.addAnimation(closeAnim)
        state2.addTransition(eventTransition2)
        
        # Add the states to the machine
        machine.addState(state1)
        machine.addState(state2)
        machine.setInitialState(state1)
        machine.start()
    
# Tree Widget
class CustomTree(QTreeWidget):

    customWidget = []

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QTreeWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        # Create top level items
        itemCount = 3
        for element in range(itemCount):
            topLevelItem = QTreeWidgetItem()
            self.addTopLevelItem(topLevelItem)

            # Replace the top level items with the expandable custom widget:
            # Get the Model Index to each item
            modelIndex = self.indexFromItem(topLevelItem, 0)
            
            # Create the ExpandableFrame widgets for all the top level items
            self.customWidget.append(ExpandableFrame())

            # Set the widget to each top level item based on its index
            self.setIndexWidget(modelIndex, self.customWidget[element])
            
            # Create more items and add them as children of the top level items
            for x in range(itemCount):
                child = QTreeWidgetItem()
                child.setText(0,'Child')
                topLevelItem.addChild(child)
```

This is how the example looks:

Minimal Code Example running:
[image: Minimal Code Example running]

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: For sure @musicamante. I edited the post and added a very simplified example. Let me know what you think.

Comment: I found out that I can return implement a ```python QTreeWidgetItem``` class and override ```python data()``` to return a new sizeHint. This open some doors. 

How can I trigger this for a specific item in the tree using a button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be to emit the `sizeHintChanged` signal of the item delegate of your view every time the size of any of the widgets is changed. This tells the view that the position of the items should be updated. To achieve this you could override the `resizeEvent` of `ExpandableFrame` and emit a custom signal, e.g.

```
class ExpandableFrame(QFrame):
    resized = pyqtSignal(QVariant)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.resized.emit(self.height())
        super().resizeEvent(event)
```

In `CustomTree`, you can then connect `ExpandableFrame.resized` to the `sizeHintChanged` signal of the delegate of the custom tree by overriding `setIndexWidget`, e.g.

```
class CustomTree(QTreeWidget):
    ...

    def setIndexWidget(self, index, widget):
        super().setIndexWidget(index, widget)
        if isinstance(widget, ExpandableFrame):
            widget.resized.connect(lambda: self.itemDelegate().sizeHintChanged.emit(index))
```

**Screen capture:**

[image: screen capture]

The disadvantage of this approach is that you would need to update the connections if the the widgets are moved or replaced.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. I have some questions though:


1. Due to my Python version(I'm still on 2.7 in Maya 2019) I had to change this to: ```super(QTreeWidget, self).setIndexWidget(index, widget)```. The widget appears but I get this error when the ```resized``` signal is triggered:


``` TypeError: resized() only accepts 0 argument(s), 1 given!```. This is how I defined the signal: ```resized = Signal()```.


2. Can you give me an example of how to update the connections if the widgets are moved or replaced?

Comment: After reading about signals I realized that if the signals carries data it have to be in the declaration. You used `QVariant` but I can `use int` which is the type returned by `height()`, so `resized = Signal(int)`.

Comment: It seems to be working perfectly know. Still I would like to know about the updating part. Thanks again for the insight @Heike.